# intl-tel-input : disable ip address info shown in console.log

Tags: javascript, jquery, intl-tel-input

tel-input .. it is showing ip and address etc info in console.log . i dont know how to disable it.

[image]

Here is my code

```
    window.rhRunIntlTelInput =  function(cfosID) {
    var rhInputIntlInput = document.querySelector(cfosID);
    window.intlTelInput(rhInputIntlInput, {

        hiddenInput: "number",
        initialCountry: "auto",
        geoIpLookup: function (callback) {
            $.get('https://ipinfo.io', function () {
            }, "jsonp").always(function (resp) {
                var countryCode = (resp && resp.country) ? resp.country : "";
                callback(countryCode);

            });
        },
        utilsScript: inspiryUtilsPath.stylesheet_directory,
    });

}
```

Comment: The console.log will be made in the `callback` argument you provide to `geoIpLookup()`. Remove it from there. Also note that just because you aren't logging the value to the console doesn't mean it's not easy to read. Anyone can see the entire response to that AJAX request in browser dev tools, regardless of how you handle it in code.

Comment: ok i have sorted it out .. thanks

Comment: Hi @rmarif how did you sort it out?

Comment: I get the same Object with city, country, ip, loc, org, postal, readme, region and timezone keys, any idea on how to remove it from the console?

Comment: Append the token parameter in the URL https://ipinfo.io/json?token=xxxxx and you will get JSON without console.log. Check here for token https://ipinfo.io/developers